# How to create a method of images for two conducting planes that meet at a right angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Two conducting planes meeting at a right angle with a point charge q located at (x, y, z) = (a, 0, a) .

The conducting planes are located on the x and z axis.

My answer was one negative charge at (-a, 0, a) and another negative charge at (a, 0, -a). That way the potential at the x and z axis will be 0.

The answer book states that a positive charge at (-a, 0, -a) is needed, because '' One can visualise that the mirror charges at (a, 0, −a) and (−a, 0, a) would induce (positive) surface charges on the conducting planes located at (0, 0, z) and (x, 0, 0), respectively ''.

I have a hard time picturing why this would mean that there is a positive surface charge on the conducting planes, and why does a third image charge solve this?

Comment: *The conducting planes are located on the x and z axis.* What does this mean? Planes are not located on axes.

Comment: With two negative image charges, are the two conducting planes equipotential surfaces?

Comment: Note that you are not putting the negative charges one by one but all at once.The charge at (-a,0,a) makes the "z axis plane" equipotential but dont forget that the (a,0,-a) is also present there and disrupts the equipotentiality of the "z plane".Similarly the effect of charge (a,0,-a) to make the "x axis plane" an equipotential surface,cannot be achieved due to presence of the 1st image charge at (-a,0,a)! To balance this effect we need to introduce a third positive charge placed symmetrically at (-a,0,-a).

Comment: Also,as pointed out by G. Smith-- planes are not located on axes,which is why i called gave quotes in "x axis plane" and  "z axis plane" in the previous comment.
As this is a very well known problem,what you clearly meant is,what can be called Y-Z plane and X-Y plane.